# courier-authlib: s_connect() failed: No such file or directory

Tags: server, email, postfix, pam, gitlab

I'm installing [GitLab](http://gitlab.com) for my work, I'm doing it on **Ubuntu Server** available 16.04.1 and everything is running pretty well.

The only thing I need to do now is to configure the *Reply by email* feature because we are interested about the concept so we want to enable it.

The **good news** is, on the [GitLab website](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reply_by_email_postfix_setup.html), there is a [detailed how-to](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reply_by_email_postfix_setup.html) telling you how to put this in place. Basically, this feature uses Postfix and is based on Courier Mail Server (at least as I can understand). The **bad news** is, on this [how-to](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reply_by_email_postfix_setup.html), everything goes well but the really last part, about testing the final IMAP setup (i.e. *Test the final setup* section), fails every time.

So, when I try to retrieve the contents of the IMAP folder with the following command, as requested in the [how-to](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reply_by_email_postfix_setup.html):

```
telnet <my.server.here> 143
```

I get this result:

```
<my_name>@<my_host>:~$ telnet <ip> 143
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <ip>.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE ACL ACL2=UNION] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2011 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.
a login incoming <my_cool_pwd>
* BYE Temporary problem, please try again later
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I looked for several logs files, and after 4 hours of research, I'm really lost.

The contents of the `/var/log/mail.err` is the following:

```
Oct 18 17:37:23 <my_host> imapd: authdaemon: s_connect() failed: No such file or directory
Oct 18 17:37:23 <my_host> imapd: authentication error: No such file or directory
```

The contents of `/var/log/mail.log` is:

```
Oct 18 17:37:10 <my_host> imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Oct 18 17:37:23 <my_host> imapd: authdaemon: s_connect() failed: No such file or directory
Oct 18 17:37:23 <my_host> imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=incoming, ip=[::ffff:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Oct 18 17:37:23 <my_host> imapd: authentication error: No such file or directory
```

When I try something simple, that command below, it fails in the same way. So it seems to be related to [PAM Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules)?

```
sudo authtest incoming <my_cool_pwd>
```

The output of the above command is:

```
ERR: authdaemon: s_connect() failed: No such file or directory
Authentication FAILED: No such file or directory
```

Exactly the same stuff. The thing is, I really don't know what file/directory is involved!

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I figured out what's going wrong after playing with the `strace` command.

The service `courier-authdaemon`, part of `courier-imap` package, wasn't launched automatically at startup for some reason.

To definitively fix this problem, execute the following:

1. Define the `courier-authdaemon` service to run at startup: `sudo systemctl enable courier-authdaemon`.
2. Start the `courier-authdaemon` service for the current session with `sudo service courier-authdaemon start`, or if you want you can just restart your server with `sudo reboot`.

After enabling the `courier-authdaemon` service, you can check that everything is OK by using the `authtest` command: 
`sudo authtest <login> <pwd>`.

You should have an output like:

```
    Authentication succeeded.

     Authenticated: <login>  (system username: <login>)
    Home Directory: /home/<login>
           Maildir: (none)
             Quota: (none)
Encrypted Password: <hidden>
Cleartext Password: <hidden>
           Options: (none)
```

I used these resources to solve my problem:

- [Courier-IMAP (Official Home)](http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/INSTALL.html#install)
- [[Courier-imap] Authdaemon error](https://sourceforge.net/p/courier/mailman/message/11790851/)
- [courier-authdaemon not starting on boot on Xenial Xerus](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322489)

So now I can continue to follow the [GitLab tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reply_by_email_postfix_setup.html#configure-postfix-to-receive-email-from-the-internet).